# Is CW complex unique if skeletons are fixed?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $(X,E),(X,E')$ be CW-complexes. ($E,E'$ are collections of cells in $X$)

If $n$-skeleton of $(X,E)$ is equal to $n$-skeleton of $(X,E')$ for all $n$, is $E=E'$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? Do you know any counterexample for this? $X$ is given as a CW-space and $E,E'$ are Whitehead complexes which have the same $n$-skeletons as $X^n$.

Comment: I proved that this is true. I will post an answer if I have some time later